# Retrieve Admin Password from router

Tags: passwords, wifi

There is a way to retrieve a router admin password without hard reset?
I'm loggen on LAN and know username and local ip address...

TKS

Comment: It's a password. If it was retrievable, the box would be hackable. So, no.

Answer (score 5):

The only way to retrieve your router's password would be by brute-forcing using tools like [THC Hydra](http://freeworld.thc.org/thc-hydra/).

As you stated, it would be much simpler to reset the configuration.